# android drag an imageview and drop on another imageview

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-imageview, ontouchlistener, onlongclicklistener

I am a bit confused with the whole Drag n Drop thing.
I am trying to Drag my application's icon and place it inside an image(the user should determine the position).

I 've read the google documentation over Drag and Drop and I have managed to make it work partially, but I have some questions.

I have seen some examples, where the author, implemented both OnTouchListener and OnLongClickListener, beside the OnDragListener.

Do I have to implement both of these listeners?

On another case, I noticed, that OnDragListener and one of the other two, where applied to the same object.

From what I have noticed, I must apply the OnDragListener on the View that is going to handle the object that will be dragged and dropped, on which I must implement the OnTouchListener (or the OnLongClickListener).

Am I right?

Now, to my project:

I have this Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_displayed"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/christmas"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewCustomize"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imagStamp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

where the first ImageView, holds an image chosen from the user, and on the second ImageView, I place the icon of the application.

Till now, I have the OnLongClickListener:

```
imageStamp.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)v.getTag());
                String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};

                ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(),mimeTypes, item);
                Customize.MyDragShadowBuilder myShadow = new Customize.MyDragShadowBuilder(imageStamp);

                v.startDrag(dragData,myShadow,null,0);
                imageStamp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

where, `MyDragShadowBuilder` is an inner class, taken from google.

My OnDragListener, is a mixing from different sources (definitely with errors):

```
imageView.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction()) {
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                        layoutParamsStamp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");

                        // Do nothing
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
                        int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                        int y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                        if(x_cord > imageView.getWidth()){
                            x_cord = imageView.getWidth();
                        }
                        else if(x_cord < 0){
                            x_cord = 0;
                        }
                        if(y_cord > imageView.getHeight()){
                            y_cord = imageView.getHeight();
                        }
                        else if(y_cord < 0){
                            y_cord = 0;
                        }
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsnew = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                        layoutParamsnew.leftMargin = x_cord - imageStamp.getWidth()/2;
                        layoutParamsnew.topMargin = y_cord - imageStamp.getHeight()/2;
                        imageStamp.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsnew);
                        imageStamp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
                        x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                        y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                        if(x_cord > imageView.getWidth()){
                            x_cord = imageView.getWidth();
                        }
                        else if(x_cord < 0){
                            x_cord = 0;
                        }
                        if(y_cord > imageView.getHeight()){
                            y_cord = imageView.getHeight();
                        }
                        else if(y_cord < 0){
                            y_cord = 0;
                        }
                        layoutParamsStamp.leftMargin = x_cord;
                        layoutParamsStamp.topMargin = y_cord;
                        v.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsStamp);
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");
                        x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                        y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                        if(x_cord > imageView.getWidth()){
                            x_cord = imageView.getWidth();
                        }
                        else if(x_cord < 0){
                            x_cord = 0;
                        }
                        if(y_cord > imageView.getHeight()){
                            y_cord = imageView.getHeight();
                        }
                        else if(y_cord < 0){
                            y_cord = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED   :
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");
                        imageStamp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        // Do nothing
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                        Log.d(msg, "ACTION_DROP event");
                        // Do nothing
                        break;
                    default: break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated, especially answers, on the former questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Do I have to implement both of these listeners?" -- no. "I must apply the OnDragListener on the View that is going to handle the object that will be dragged and dropped, on which I must implement the OnTouchListener (or the OnLongClickListener). Am I right?" -- I did not understand your description. `OnDragListener` is used on what other toolkits would call the "drop target" (the `View` over which you want to drop something else). What your trigger is to call `startDrag()`/`startDragAndDrop()` is up to you (long-click is typical but not required).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. You covered me with your replies. As for the description, I meant that OnDragListener should be implemented by the "taget View" and the OnLongClickListener or OnTouchListener by the "source"